# Why do I get 403 on my Azure MVC3 site unless I change OS to Win 2008 R2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, azure, iis-7.5

I have recently updated to the latest SDK 1.7 and made some changes to my MVC3 app. When I publish to Azure I now get a 403 on all pages.

If I go to the Azure Portal and change my web role to use OS Windows 2008 R2 the error goes away and my app works. However every time I re-deploy I have to change the Role to use 2008 R2 any ideas?

Is it a Web.config issue that the later version of IIS handles? Any idea what to change to get this to work again?

I don't think I have made any routing changes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't answer why this issue is happening, but you can change the default OS so you no longer have to update the OS every time you deploy.  MS have a [full description of what to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456324).

The short version is open you service config (.csfg) file and update the `ServiceConfiguration` node so it contains the element `osFamily="2"` and also `osVersion="*"` e.g. :

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyCloudProject" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="2" osVersion="*">
```